# Laravel middleware redirection

Tags: laravel-5

when i use laravel middleware its routes is not work properly

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;



class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth',['only'=>'create']);
    }
    //
    public function index(){
        //return \Auth::user();
        $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get();
        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }

    public function show($id){
        $article = Article::findorFail($id);
        //dd($article->published_at->addDays(8)->diffForHumans());

        return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
    }
    public function create(){
        if(Auth::guest()){
            return redirect('articles');
        }
        return view('articles.create');
    }
    public function store(ArticleRequest $request){
        /*
        $input = Request::all();
        $input['published_at'] = Carbon::now();
        */
        $article = new Article($request->all());
        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

        //Article::create($request->all());
        return redirect('articles');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $article = Article::findorFail($id);
        return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
    }

    public function update($id, ArticleRequest $request){
        $article = Article::findorFail($id);
        $article->update($request->all());

        return redirect('articles');
    }
}
```

when i go to http://localhost/lernlaravel/public/articles/create it works fine
but when i go to http://localhost/learnlaravel/public/articles it redirect to http://localhost/articles.

index() method is used for listing articles how i can fix it?

Comment: You have a problem with your server configuration. You should point your root folder to "public". Are you using Apache, ngix? serving through php?

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect ()` accepts a URL path so if you want ensure your redirect will work on both testing and production environments, I would pass either `action ()` or `route ()` to all of your applications redirect calls. In your this case I would go with

`return redirect(action ('ArticlesController@show', $articles->id));`

This way Laravel will automatically generate the proper URL path to the controller you want to handle the request.

If you choose to go with `route()` you are required to have named the route in your routes file, but I find that with resourceful controllers it's less complicated to go with action.